# Is there a way to display the last li element of a ul element that overflows its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Background**

I'm working on a chat app in react where I have a ul element that displays messages using li elements. 
At some point the ul element overflows its parent element.

**Problem**

Now, the problem is when I switch chats. Is there a way I can make the ul element display the li elements that have overflowed, that is, display the last li elements of the ul element instead of displaying from the first li elements and have the user scroll to the bottom because that would make for a terrible user experience.

I tried using the scrollIntoView() method to make the ul element scroll to the last message whenever a new li element is added and this works fine while the user is in a chat but once the user switches chats, the new chat's ul element visibly scrolls to the last element in it. I would like to display the elements from the bottom without the ul element scrolling at all.

**Code Sample**

```
const MessagingScreen = ({ openChat }) => {
  const messagesEnd = useRef();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (openChat.messages.length > 0) {
      messagesEnd.current.scrollIntoView({ behaivor: "smooth", block: "start" });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [openChat.messages])

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-column flex-grow mh-50">
        <ul className="chat-msgs flex-grow w-100 h-100 bg-white overflow-y-scroll instant">
          {openChat.messages.map(chatMessageDetails =>
            <ChatMessageItem {...chatMessageDetails} key={chatMessageDetails.message}/>)
          }
          <div ref={messagesEnd}/>
        </ul>
     </main>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Bebian, welcome to Stack Overflow. The solution likely depends on the context of your <ul> element. Could you provide a code sample that demonstrates the issue you're having?

Comment: Thanks @totallyuneekname, great to be here. I'll add a code sample in an edit to the question now

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for `scrollTop`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Explicitly setting `scrollTop` of an element will scroll it instantly to the value you specify.

You would use this in conjunction with `scrollHeight`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

`scrollHeight` is the total amount the element can scroll, including the invisible bits that are overflowed.

So an example would be:

```
var myListElement = document.getElementById('myList');
myListElement.scrollTop = myListElement.scrollHeight
```

throwing this in your start function should scroll the list to the bottom on init. `scrollTop` is 0 at the start and should be set to the max `scrollHeight` on init.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Sean. I get what you're saying and I've tried it out but it still changes position visibly. Looking into it, although setting the scrollTop property does cause the element to scroll to a position instantly, I seem to be only be able to set the scrollTop property after the list element has mounted thereby making the list initially start at the top first before being scrolled to the bottom thus making the change visible.

Comment: You're using react right? Why can't you have an element ref and check when current is available and then scroll? So in your componentDidUpdate() check if this.myElementRef.current and if true then scroll to where you want, it should be instantaneous. I'm using it currently one of my projects, just also have a flag to only do this once or it will always scroll on every update

Comment: Hmm, I think that's what I'm already doing. If you check the edit I made to the question, I added code from the project and the scroll behavior is still visible, is that what you mean or something else?